# Need assistance solving exponential equation: $64=0.8^d$x$100$

Tags: exponentiation

Solve the exponential equation: $64=0.8^d \cdot100$ 
I tried doing: $64/100=80/100^d$ but since there is no common factor which gives these numbers with different powers I failed to find the value of variable $d$. How to solve it then?

Comment: If you think of it as $64/100=(8/10)^d$ the answer will be clear.

Comment: You could always be "dumb" and simply use: $a^x = b \rightarrow x = \frac{\log(b)}{\log(a)}$ (I'm guessing you're supposed to do this without a calculator though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$64/100 = .64$$

So then you have $.8^d = .64$

What does $.8 \times .8$ equal?